# sysadmin security error creating Reporting Services cache refresh plan in Report Manager

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, ssrs

On SQL Server 2012 (SP1) Reporting Services (native), when creating a cache refresh plan in Report Manager, I receive the error:

```
Only members of sysadmin role are allowed to update or delete jobs owned by a different login.
```

This is unexpected because:

1. Isn't it creating a job, not updating or deleting an existing one?
2. The owner_sid of all the existing jobs in the "Reporting Services" category is that of `NT Service\ReportServer`. (Not sure how these were ever successfully created, somebody else must have created them.)
3. `NT Service\ReportServer` is in the `SQLAgentOperatorRole` in `msdb`.
4. The service is indeed running as `NT Service\ReportServer`.

I can "fix" this by giving `NT Service\ReportServer` the `sysadmin` (thus verifying the login being used is really `NT Service\ReportServer`). However, that level of access shouldn't be necessary given the facts above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on CU7 or CU8, you may be hitting the issue mentioned [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2926089) since cache refresh plans also make use of SQL Agent. If so, updating to the newest CU should fix it